# emacs split window side by side independently

Tags: emacs

My question is whether it's possible (simply!) to split a buffer window into two side by side frames which are independent, so that for example in org mode expanding a headline in one frame does not affect that headline in the other frame? C-x 2 does this for a top/bottom split but C-x 3 splits the screen but the buffers are not independent. On my laptop two side by side frames would be much easier to work with than a top/bottom split.

Comment: You make it sound like `C-x 2` does what you want except for the way the windows are positioned -- but there is absolutely no difference between `C-x 2` and `C-x 3` when it comes to how the resulting windows and buffers behave.  They are not "independent" with one of those and "not independent" with the other.  You may want to clarify the question.

Comment: Sorry. You're right. I think what I must actually have tried was the solution below of C-x 4-c which I must have found somewhere but it split the window top/bottom. I didn't realise that  if you split side by side first it would work the way I wanted! Good to know that emacs is not orthogonally biased!

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> calls `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window` which I believe is the closest thing to what you're asking for.

That command doesn't enforce any particular window split, but Emacs may do what you want by default.  If not, then it will do what you want if the frame is *already* split appropriately, such that the 'other' window is where you want the indirect clone to be.

i.e.:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

See the manual for more information:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Indirect Buffers`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It means that for longer documents in org mode you can have the structure in the form of headings on the left and the content either fully or partially expanded on the left. If you want to reorder the document, dragging the headings on the left does the job. Emacs is amazing.